# Console logs not getting printed via org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job's waitForCompletion(true) method

Tags: java, hadoop, java-8, mapreduce, hadoop2

As the documentation for waitForCompletion(Boolean xxx) method states that

> The waitForCompletion() method on Job submits the job and waits for it to finish. The single argument to the method is a flag indicating whether verbose output is generated. When true, the job writes information about its progress to the console.

In my following exercise, I'm setting up this single arguement as true. But still the verbose output is not getting printed on console.
Here is my code:

```
public class MaxTemperature extends Configured implements Tool {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperature(), args);
      System.exit(exitCode);
  }

  @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
              System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
              System.exit(-1);
            }
        System.out.println("Starting job");
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
        job.setJobName("Max temperature");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;

        if(job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was successful");
        } else if(!job.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Job was not successful");           
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

And here is the console:

```
Starting job
Job was successful
```

And Here is my log4j.properties file in resources folder:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA

log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Any suggestion, why the information about job progress and details is not getting printed?

Comment: @franklinsijo Nothing specifically. Just to check the int value that needs to be returned so as to stop the job.

Comment: Can you update the post with the hadoop `log4j.properties`.

Comment: @franklinsijo Pls check now.